# How to include zero occurrences in group by clause result set EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

A table has event logs, I want to find out the counts of each eventType given the types in where clause. The problem is that if i pass event types in where clause, I only get back events that match the condition, I want to return 0 for events that do not match. For example:

```
     var data = await (from eventLogs in _context.Set<EventLog>()
                          where (eventTypes.Contains(eventLogs.EventType))
                          group eventLogs by eventLogs.EventType
                          into log
                          select new
                          {
                              EventType = log.Key,
                              Occurrences = log.Count()
                          })
                         .ToDictionaryAsync(x => x.EventType, x => x.Occurrences);
```

Results

| Event Type | Heading 2 |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | 34 |
| 52 | 3 |

Desired result

| Event Type | Heading 2 |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | 34 |
| 52 | 3 |
| 71 | 0 |

Comment: I assume `eventTypes` contains the three event types you're interested in?

Comment: @DStanley, yes. I want result include all eventTypes that were passed in "Where" condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume eventlogs doesnt have any  records with typeId =71. So you can make an union

```
 var data1 = await (from eventLogs in _context.Set<EventLog>()
                          where (eventTypes.Contains(eventLogs.EventType))
                          group eventLogs by eventLogs.EventType
                          into log
                          select new
                          {
                              EventType = log.Key,
                              Occurrences = log.Count()
                          })
                         .ToListAsync();

var data2 = eventTypes.Select(i=> new
{
     EventType = i,
    Occurrences = 0
}).ToList();

var data = data1.Union(data2).GroupBy(o => new {o.EventType})
                .Select(o => new 
                {
                    EventType = o.Key.EventType ,
                    Occurrences = o.Sum(q => q.Occurrences )
                }).ToDictionary(x => x.EventType, x => x.Occurrences);
```

Comment: I hoped there would be some kind of EF core magic to format the data on SQL side but I guess we have to append/union no matching elements in the memory after data is fetched from SQL Server. Thank you, that works for now.